# Combine two records to be one record in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

How to group by when getting data 'Pej. Pesaka Kecil' and 'Pej. Tanah Daerah' for example:

```
DECLARE @fMonth AS VARCHAR(20) = '1'
DECLARE @fYear AS VARCHAR(5) = '2017'
DECLARE @tMonth AS VARCHAR(20) = '5'
DECLARE @tYear AS VARCHAR(5) = '2017'


select * from (
    select @fMonth AS fMonth, @fYear AS fYear, @tMonth AS tMonth, @tYear AS tYear,
    (case when Description in ('Pej. Pesaka Kecil', 'Pej. Tanah Daerah') then 'JKPTG'
                 else Description
            end) as description, [state_desc]


    from B_Requestor as main
    left join B_Party as b on  main.requestorid = b.requestorid
    left join B_BlueCard as blue on b.partyid = blue.partyid and YEAR(blue.AppliedDate) = @fYear and blue.CardType = 'Form C'
    group by  state, category, (case when description in ('Pej. Pesaka Kecil', 'Pej. Tanah Daerah') then 'JKPTG' else Description 
      end) ,[state_desc]
) t
    order by  (case when description =  'Amanah Raya Berhad' then 1
                                       when description = 'Mahkamah Tinggi' then 2
                                       when description = 'JKPTG' then 3
                                       END) ASC, [state_desc]
```

Current output has the correct result, but needs to be grouped based on `Description` and `State_desc`. But want to keep all current columns in the output.

Thank you guys.

Comment: Can you post your current output? So we can understand what is not matching with your expected output.

Comment: @PM. : current output https://gyazo.com/2f178ccde7cff52121713f6f7ff1d20d

Comment: this problem cannot be solved if you don't include sample data.

Comment: Are you sure? I don't see any difference in your expected output and current output. Can you highlight the difference?

Comment: @PM. : can I email with you?

Comment: @PM. i try to change the another code, but still the same record twice. https://gyazo.com/3174ae894a0ddb00651383b59e617d69

Comment: sure, are you in any chat room?

Comment: Oh got it now, you want to group the result by description and state_desc. See my answer below

Comment: i at chat room SQL

Comment: can we exchange email? ikramlim@gmail.com

Comment: I have sent you an email, also you can join here: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141399/lim-khs-issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select MAX(fMonth),MAX(fYear),MAX(tMonth),MAX(tYear),[description],[state_desc] from (
    select @fMonth AS fMonth, @fYear AS fYear, @tMonth AS tMonth, @tYear AS tYear,
    (case when Description in ('Pej. Pesaka Kecil', 'Pej. Tanah Daerah') then 'JKPTG'
                 else Description
            end) as description, [state_desc]
    from BKM_Requestor as main
    left join BKM_Party as b on  main.requestorid = b.requestorid
    left join BKM_BlueCard as blue on b.partyid = blue.partyid and YEAR(blue.AppliedDate) = @fYear and blue.CardType = 'Form C'
    group by  state, category, (case when description in ('Pej. Pesaka Kecil', 'Pej. Tanah Daerah') then 'JKPTG' else Description 
      end) ,[state_desc]
) t
group by [description],[state_desc]
    order by  (case when description =  'Amanah Raya Berhad' then 1
                                       when description = 'Mahkamah Tinggi' then 2
                                       when description = 'JKPTG' then 3
                                       END) ASC, [state_desc]
```